# Monte Carlo Integration in R from normal distribution

Tags: r, montecarlo

Monte Carlo Question in R. I have the following equation.

h(x)=x/((3^x)-1)

I am trying to compute a estimator for the integral where random variables are generated from N(0,1).

The following code works in generating the correct value:

```
set.seed(1)
x<-runif(1000,0,1)
x2<-(x/((3^x)-1))

result<-mean(x2)
print(result)
```

However this is using uniform r.v's. When I modify to runif to rnorm I am not getting the desired value. I tried multiplying the h(x) equation by the pdf of norm as well.

Attempt at normal:

```
    set.seed(1)
xlist<-rnorm(n=10000, mean=0, sd=1)
result<-0
for (x in xlist)
{
  a1<-(1*sqrt(2*pi))/((exp((-1/2)*((x-0)/1)^2)))
  a2<-(x/((3^x)-1))
  a3<-a1*a2
  result<-result+a3
}
print (result/n)
```

Comment: Is this a defined integral? What are the limits?

Comment: It is defined. upper bound =1, lower bound =0.

Comment: The function is not defined at x=0 but its limit as x approaches 0 is 1/log(3).

Comment: You should show us the modification you used.  Since you want to integrate from 0 to 1 and rnorm() doesn't produce values in that range, you need to set the integrand to zero where it doesn't make sense.  And you should normally divide by the pdf, not multiply by it.  You'll also need a much bigger sample from rnorm for the same accuracy.

Comment: In your updated code, there's no need for a `for` loop:  All of the calculations are vectorized, so you can do them on all of `xlist` at once.  But you really do need to limit `xlist` to the range `[0,1]`.  So you could use `mean( ifelse(0 < xlist & xlist < 1, xlist/(3^xlist - 1)/dnorm(xlist), 0))`.  (This is importance sampling.)

Answer (score 2):

Here's how I would go about this. First, let's examine the function we want to integrate:

```r
f <- function(x) (x/((3^x)-1))

curve(f)
```

[image]

We can see that in the interval 0, 1, the maximum and minimum values of the function are between 0 and 1. We can see that the integral is less than 1, and must be some proportion of the unit square bounded by x = 0, x = 1, y = 0 and y = 1.

This means that if we create uniform random points on the unit square, the proportion that fall below the line will approximate the integral of the function. We can simulate the points like this:

```r
set.seed(1)
xvals <- runif(1e6)
yvals <- runif(1e6)
```

Note that if, for some reason, you are constrained to use `rnorm` rather than `runif`, you can get the same effect by doing

```r
set.seed(1)
xvals <- pnorm(rnorm(1e6))
yvals <- pnorm(rnorm(1e6))
```

In either case our answer is just the proportion of these points that are below our line:

```r
sum(yvals < f(xvals)) / length(xvals)
#> [1] 0.691146
```

This is pretty close to the actual value of 0.690395, as you can see [on Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=integrate+x%2F%28%283%5Ex%29-1%29+between+0+and+1).

<sup>Created on 2022-03-13 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>